# Event on double click the background but not elements

Tags: jquery

```
$( 'body' ).dblclick(function() {
    alert("You double-clicked the background!");
});​
```

How can I match the body background but not elements linke input or links? I gues using `:not()`, but it can't get it working.

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/SwARj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [event.target.nodeName](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) to check which element was double clicked.

e.g.:

```
$( 'body' ).dblclick(function() {
   if (event.target.nodeName != "A" && event.target.nodeName != "INPUT")
      alert("You double-clicked the background and not a link nor an input");
});​
```

Comment: Like in the other answer(s), better to check that the current element IS the body than that the current element does NOT match something else - that could get pretty hairy if there is any moderate amount of markup in the page.

Comment: Well, I was answering his question more specifically. If @Martin wants to exclude only some dom elements, my answer is the way to go. If @Martin wants to exclude all other dom elements than `body` then I agree with you, @jesus.thesh

Comment: @"better to check that the current element IS the body" >> isn't that done by `$('body').dblclick()`?

Comment: @Martin well events bubble in javascript. so when you click a link, the click event on the link is fired as well as on all parent elements including the body. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/SwARj/5/

Answer (score 7):

http://jsfiddle.net/SwARj/1/

```
$( 'body' ).dblclick(function(e) {
    if($(e.target).is('body')){
        alert("You double-clicked the background!");
    }
});​
```

Comment: I like this version better than my answer, as it uses the 'is' operator with a selector, making it more versatile. +1

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for The event object in jquery: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

With that in mind, you can say "if the target element is the `body` element, then process"

I updated your jsfiddle accordingly:
http://jsfiddle.net/SwARj/2/

```
$( 'body' ).dblclick(function(evt)
{
    if(evt.target == document.body)
        alert("You double-clicked the background!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').dblclick(function(e) {
    if (e.target.localName === 'body') {
      //...
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gXZyw/